# Как массово удалить файлы связанной модели в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, события, relation, observer, laravel-5.6

Компания. У компании товары - связь один ко многим.
При удалении компании, необходимо удалить все связанные товары **и их изображения**! Сами товары из БД удаляются как нужно, но вот событие не подхватывается (Не выводится сообщение "ОК")! Пробовал через Events - тоже не получается.
Через Observer выглядит таким образом:

Метод удаления компании:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $company = Company::findOrFail($id);

    // удаляем связанные товары
    $company->goods()->delete();

    // удаляем компанию
    $company->delete();

    return redirect()->route('...');
}
```

Связь в модели компании:

```
public function goods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Good', 'company_id' , 'id');
}
```

Метод удаления товара:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $good = Good::findOrFail($id);

    // удаление товара + вызов Observer
    $good->delete();

    return redirect()->route('...');
}
```

Регистрация Observer в AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Good::observe(GoodObserver::class);
}
```

Код Observer:

```
class GoodObserver
{
    public function deleting(Good $good)
    {
        dd('OK'); // вывод сообщения об удалении
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще вызов `$company->goods()->delete();` можно было бы и не делать.
Если у вас созданы `foreign keys` и имеет место каскадное удаление, то связные элементы удалятся автоматически.
В миграции `create_goods_table` это выглядит так:
`$table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('сompanies')->onDelete('cascade');`.
Ну а попутное удаление картинок я делают так:
В модели `Good` переопределяем метод `boot`

```
protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($good) {
            unlink($good->imgPath);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Каскадное удаление это хорошо, но как при удалении компании, удалить все товары вместе с их картинками, избежав каких либо foreach(...) {}

Comment: Ну да, тут согласен. Тогда оставляйте сввой код + допишите function boot в модель товаров.